# Cramer's V with missing values gives different results

Tags: r, correlation

My questions concern the calculation of the Cramers V to detect  correlation between categorial variables. I 've got a dataset with missing values, but I created a fake dataset for illustration with two variables a and b, one of them containing to NA's.

```
 a <-  factor(c("M","","F","F","","M","F","F"))
a2 <- factor(a, levels = c('M','F'),labels =c('Male','Female'))
b <- factor(c("y","y","","y","n","n","n","y"))
b2 <- factor(b, levels=c("y","n"),labels=c("yes","no"))
df<-cbind(a2,b2)
```

The assocstats function gives me the result for the cramers V:

```
require(vcd)
> tab <-table(a,b)
> assocstats(tab)
                            X^2 df P(> X^2)
Likelihood Ratio 1.7261  4  0.78597
Pearson          1.3333  4  0.85570

Phi-Coefficient   : 0.408 
Contingency Coeff.: 0.378 
Cramer's V        : 0.289
```

Now I want to drop the NA's from the levels

```
   a[a==""]<-NA
    a3 <- droplevels(a)
    levels(a3)

    tab <-table(a,b)
    assocstats(tab)
```

But everytime I remove NA's the result looks like this:

```
                    X^2 df P(> X^2)
Likelihood Ratio 0.13844  2  0.93312
Pearson              NaN  2      NaN

Phi-Coefficient   : NaN 
Contingency Coeff.: NaN 
Cramer's V        : NaN
```

Also, because I have a large dataset I would like to calculate a matrix of the Cramer V results. I found this code here on stack overflow and it seems to work...

```
get.V<-function(y){
  col.y<-ncol(y)
  V<-matrix(ncol=col.y,nrow=col.y)
  for(i in 1:col.y){
    for(j in 1:col.y){
      V[i,j]<-assocstats(table(y[,i],y[,j]))$cramer
    }
  }
  return(V)
}

   get.V(tab)
```

Only that the result is different than that with assocstats function:

```
   [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  1.0  0.5    1
[2,]  0.5  1.0    1
[3,]  1.0  1.0    1
```

This can not be right, because I get this result every time, even when changing the number of observations... what is wrong with this code?

Conclusion:I don't know which one of the result is right. I have a large dataset with a lot of NA's in it. The first asocstat result and the code give different results, altough there is no big difference,because the code only creates a matrix. The second asocstat function gives only NaN.I cant detect any errors... Can somebody help me?

Comment: since you aren't defining `""` as a level in a2 and b2, isn't that the data you want (ie, you don't need to create a3: `a[a==""]<-NA; a3 <- droplevels(a)`)? when you make a table, you must explicitly use `table(..., useNA = 'ifany')` in order to keep NAs, so in effect you are already excluding them. So `assocstats(table(a2,b2))` should work

Comment: In my dataset I have a level " " and I have to remove them with droplevels, that why I created this data set this way, I don't want to keep NA's. And I don't understand why the asocstats function creates NaN when removing them

Comment: I think you got NaN cause you removed them in a and dropped the levels for a3 but you did not do the same for b

Comment: Use `complete.cases` to index a dataframe. Don't just omit NA's from single vectors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to replace the `""` with `NA` if you are using factors--any unique value that you don't define in `levels` will be converted to `NA` by `factor`

```
a <-  factor(c("M","","F","F","","M","F","F"))
a2 <- factor(a, levels = c('M','F'),labels =c('Male','Female'))

a
# [1] M   F F   M F F
# Levels:  F M
a2
# [1] Male   <NA>   Female Female <NA>   Male   Female Female
# Levels: Male Female

b <- factor(c("y","y","","y","n","n","n","y"))
b2 <- factor(b, levels=c("y","n"),labels=c("yes","no"))


(df <- cbind(a2,b2))

#      a2 b2
# [1,]  1  1
# [2,] NA  1
# [3,]  2 NA
# [4,]  2  1
# [5,] NA  2
# [6,]  1  2
# [7,]  2  2
# [8,]  2  1
```

Above, you're creating a matrix which loses all the labels that you created with `factor`. I think you want a data frame:

```
(df <- data.frame(a2,b2))

#       a2   b2
# 1   Male  yes
# 2   <NA>  yes
# 3 Female <NA>
# 4 Female  yes
# 5   <NA>   no
# 6   Male   no
# 7 Female   no
# 8 Female  yes


require('vcd')
(tab <- table(a2,b2, useNA = 'ifany'))
#          b2
# a2       yes no <NA>
#   Male     1  1    0
#   Female   2  1    1
#   <NA>     1  1    0

(tab <- table(a2,b2))
#          b2
# a2       yes no
#   Male     1  1
#   Female   2  1
```

You need to explicitly tell `table` if you want to see `NA` values in the table. Otherwise, it will drop them by default so that you are already "excluding" them when you use `assocstats`:

```
assocstats(tab)

#                      X^2 df P(> X^2)
# Likelihood Ratio 0.13844  1  0.70983
# Pearson          0.13889  1  0.70939
# 
# Phi-Coefficient   : 0.167 
# Contingency Coeff.: 0.164 
# Cramer's V        : 0.167
```

For `get.V` just pass the data frame or matrix, not the table:

```
get.V <- function(y) {
  col.y <- ncol(y)
  V <- matrix(ncol=col.y,nrow=col.y)
  for(i in 1:col.y){
    for(j in 1:col.y){
      V[i,j] <- assocstats(table(y[,i],y[,j]))$cramer
    }
  }
  return(V)
}


get.V(df)

#           [,1]      [,2]
# [1,] 1.0000000 0.1666667
# [2,] 0.1666667 1.0000000
```

Comment: OK thanks! I think I found the error. I want to remove ` "" ` from a variable and I do  `var[var==""]<-NA
var <- droplevels(var)`
then  I want to select the dataframe with the categ variables I transformed without the empty levels :
`cat <-subset(data,select=c(var, var1, var2))'
b <-table(var,var1)
assocstats(b) ` but this dataframe still contains the variables with the empty levels! What can I do to replace them in the dataframe with the transformed variables??

Comment: you can do the entire data frame at once: `data[data == ''] <- NA`

Comment: For the get.V function output matrix, Is there a way that it replaces the column and row numbers of the matrix by the original column and row names from the dataframe ("yes", "no", "M", "F")?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with the example. each of the two columns (and each of the two rows) of the matrix would be yes/no or M/F. Do you mean you want the names of the data frame in the colnames of the matrix? like `V <- matrix(ncol = col.y, nrow = col.y, dimnames = list(names(y), names(y)))` instead of `V <- matrix(ncol=col.y,nrow=col.y)` ?